# Pullback of structure sheaf along point inclusion into locally ringed space is residue field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

I'm coming from a differential geometry background (though I'm pretty familiar with category theory) and trying to learn a bit about ringed spaces.

Let $(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ be a locally ringed space, and let $\iota_x : \{x\} \to X$ denote the inclusion of a point $x \in X$. Then based on my experience with smooth manifolds, I expect that we should define the structure sheaf of $\{x\}$ to be the residue field $\kappa(x)$ in order to get a locally ringed space structure on this point. In this case, I assume that the adjunct of the quotient map

$$\iota_x^{-1} \mathscr{O}_X \to \iota_x^{-1} \mathscr{O}_X / \mathfrak{m}_x = \kappa(x), $$

namely,

$$\iota_x^\sharp: \mathscr{O}_X \to (\iota_x)_\ast \kappa(x)$$

should be the comorphism for this inclusion. If so, this would mean that

$$(\iota_x)^*\mathscr{O}_X = \kappa(x) \otimes_{\iota_x^{-1} \mathscr{O}_X} \iota_x^{-1} \mathscr{O}_X = \kappa(x).$$

Is my reasoning correct here?

Comment: Yep. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the book I'm looking at.

Comment: What you're basically rediscovering here is that the pullback of the structure sheaf is the structure sheaf and that a very easy choice for the structure sheaf of a point in a scheme is the residue field. This may be mentioned later in your book somewhere in an exercise (maybe about what determines a map from a point in to a scheme), or maybe the authors didn't care. If you're interested in further discussion about that, you could add the book to your post.

Comment: @KReiser The book I'm reading is Torsten Wedhorn's Manifolds, Sheaves, and Cohomology. It's possible that I might have missed him pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course; locally, a morphism $Y \rightarrow X$  gives a  map of algebras $B \leftarrow A$, and for the $A$-module $M$ the pullback is defined to correspond to $B \otimes_A M$.

In your case, it is $$ k \otimes_A A = (A/m) \mathop{\otimes}_A A = A/m. $$